# SQL Exception while compiling UPDATE GroupNames SET Message=? WHERE GroupName=Group 1

Tags: android, sqlite

Created table GroupNames with GroupName and Message columns

```
db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE GroupNames (_Id  INTEGER primary key autoincrement, GroupName varchar(50),     Message varchar(120));");
```

and i am creating this table and giving groupName value in previous activity, now i want to insert the Message value in corresponding group like

```
DbHelper.storeGroupReplyMsg(replyMessage, groupName);
```

In database

```
public static final String KEY_REPLY_MESSAGE = "Message";
private static final String GROUP_NAMES_TABLE = "GroupNames";
public static final String KEY_GROUP_NAME = "GroupName";   

public void storeGroupReplyMsg(String replyMessage, String groupName) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_REPLY_MESSAGE, replyMessage);
    database.update(GROUP_NAMES_TABLE, args, KEY_GROUP_NAME + "=" + groupName, null);
}
```

why i am gerring syntax error while inserting Message ?

My logcat is

```
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Group": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE GroupNames SET Message=? WHERE GroupName=Group 1
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:890)
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:501)
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1572)
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1520)
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612):    at com.automessaging.database.ProfilesDatabaseHelper.storeGroupReplyMsg(ProfilesDatabaseHelper.java:218)
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612):    at com.automessaging.readContacts.ContactListActivity$2.onClick(ContactListActivity.java:115)
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4421)
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17903)
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214)
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
11-07 11:14:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(20612):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, strings must be quoted (and quotes in strings must be escaped).

However, to avoid SQL formatting problems like this (and SQL injection attacks), use parameters instead:

```java
database.update(GROUP_NAMES_TABLE, args,
                KEY_GROUP_NAME + "= ?", new String[]{ groupName });
```

Comment: Thank @CL for updating the answer... this is the correct solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing code from

```
database.update(GROUP_NAMES_TABLE, args, KEY_GROUP_NAME + "=" + groupName, null);
```

to

```
database.update(GROUP_NAMES_TABLE, args, KEY_GROUP_NAME + "='" + groupName+"'", null);
```

or

```
String[] stringVals = new String[]{groupName};
database.update(GROUP_NAMES_TABLE, args, KEY_GROUP_NAME + "=?", stringVals);
```

Comment: This will blow up when the string contains a quote.

Comment: The wrong call is still there, and the other one will not even compile.